# Vue - Loading all dynamic components once before rendering

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js, vue-component

I'm Working on a complex vue form, where I'm using dynamic components to render multiple parts of the form. Using  and , it first renders the default section, then the respective sections when I click on specific tabs. I have to start from "Ship From" tab but something on "Label Specification" tab depends on the Shop From section (see below img). So I can solve the problem by rendering the "Label Specification" section first. But my requirement is to start from "Ship From" section. So either I have to preload all the dynamic components or start at Label Spec then switch fast before user can see it. How can I solve the issue? here is the code for tabs and components:

```html
<button
      v-for="(tabname, index) in tabnames"
      v-bind:key="index"
      v-bind:class="['tab-button', { active: currentTabIndex === index }]"
      v-on:click="
        currentTab = tabs[index];
        currentTabIndex = index;
      "
    >
      <h3>
        <b>{{ tabname }}<span class="text-danger">* </span></b>
      </h3>
    </button>

    <keep-alive>
      <component
        v-bind:is="currentTabComponent"
        v-bind="currentProps"
        class="tab"
        @jsonresponse="
          saveSection(Object.keys(currentResponse)[0], ...arguments)
        "
      ></component>
    </keep-alive>
```

Here is img of my work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use *v-for* + *v-show* without *keep-alive* or you can create your own implementation with lazy loading.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But how can I use v-for for <component> tag?